# Shopping cart solution WITHOUT template

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart, google-checkout

I am working on redesigning a website for my fathers business based on the results of a design project I did in a class last year. The design is fairly complex but everyone who has seen it loves it. The issue I am running into is finding a good shopping cart solution that does not force an entire eCommerce 'storefront' on you.

Ill probably just end up rolling my own, I am a good programmer, but have not had to code for a security critical application like a shopping cart so I would like to avoid this portion of the coding if possible.

Ideally I would like to find a simple secure PHP shopping cart that I can add to as needed (rather than having to rip a shopping cart out of some larger eCommerce solution). Failing that, does anyone have any good suggestions on reading that could guide me in creating my own, secure, shopping cart implementation?

Comment: you could use a remotely hosted cart, like paypal offers.

Comment: Will Shopify allow you to do what you need? Better not to chance your lack of experience with security-minded development and let the pros do their work.

Comment: It looks like I could use Shopify, but I would need to learn their Liquid language it would appear. I just went back and looked at Google Checkout and they have a new "Checkout Shopping Cart" that, if I only want to use Google Checkout, looks like it will work very well. http://goo.gl/xwsSa if anyone finds this and wants to look at it. That said I am still interested in some better shopping cart only solutions. Thanks for the comments so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Checkout XML API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html) allows you to handle all the cart operations yourself. A basic implementation *could* merely implement the checkout operation, and handle order processing through the Google Merchant Centre.

There's plenty of code and detail on their website, and it essentially boils down to submitting XML documents via POST requests between your server and the Google servers. There is also [a HTML API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API.html) as an option, although I've only ever used the XML API.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but you could use something like [Moltin](https://molt.in). Just pick the API components you need and integrate them into whatever frontend you have. Comes with a backend dashboard if you need one also.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for a fee, paypal can give you an "integrateable" payment page, never tried it but any way I think this is the best solution.